# MSB401 The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly. System.IO.IOException

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have an XF solution that used to work flawlessly until last week.

This weekend I updated my VS2017 to the latest version i.e. v 15.9.24 and I started getting this compile-time error which says that my `classes.jar` is being used by another process. No other processes in my knowledge should be using it!!!

The previous version of Visual studio I had was v 15.9.12.

This happens only in the Android project rest seems to build just fine.

Any suggestions are welcomed.

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error       The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly.
> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'ProjPath\obj\Debug\90\lp\45\jl\bin\classes.jar' because it is being used by another process.
> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
> at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
> at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
> at System.IO.File.OpenFile(String path, FileAccess access, SafeFileHandle& handle)
> at System.IO.File.SetLastAccessTimeUtc(String path, DateTime lastAccessTimeUtc)
> at Xamarin.Android.Tools.Files.ExtractAll(ZipArchive zip, String destination, Action`2 progressCallback, Func`2 modifyCallback, Func`2 deleteCallback, Boolean forceUpdate) at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Extract(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res, ICollection`1 jars, ICollection`1 resolvedResourceDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedAssetDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedEnvironments)
> at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Execute()
> at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
> at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() FoodSafety.Android

Output:

> ------ Rebuild All started: Project: FoodSafety.Android, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2110,5): warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.CSharp" that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1327,2): error MSB4018: The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly.
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1327,2): error MSB4018: System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'ProjPath\obj\Debug\90\lp\45\jl\bin\classes.jar' because it is being used by another process.
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1327,2): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1327,2): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1327,2): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1327,2): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.File.OpenFile(String path, FileAccess access, SafeFileHandle& handle)
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1327,2): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.File.SetLastAccessTimeUtc(String path, DateTime lastAccessTimeUtc)
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1327,2): error MSB4018:    at Xamarin.Android.Tools.Files.ExtractAll(ZipArchive zip, String destination, Action`2 progressCallback, Func`2 modifyCallback, Func`2 deleteCallback, Boolean forceUpdate) C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1327,2): error MSB4018:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Extract(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res, ICollection`1 jars, ICollection`1 resolvedResourceDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedAssetDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedEnvironments)
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1327,2): error MSB4018:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Execute()
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1327,2): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(1327,2): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()
> ========== Rebuild All: 2 succeeded, 2 failed, 0 skipped ==========

### UPDATE

**Now it seems no matter what solution I open there is always this error in the Android project. Even if I create a new project :/**

Comment: Why aren't you using latest VS 2019? Also, you can try to repair VS 2017. If repairing doesn't help, try clearing VS' cache - https://errorhandlinginskills.wordpress.com/2018/07/28/how-to-clear-visual-studio-cache/

Comment: @MihailDuchev I have tried all this beforehand and nothing seems to work, Also the issue exists in both 19 and 17 but I started getting this issue after I updated my VS17 to latest.

Comment: Try clearing the Android Library Cache C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\XamarinBuildDownloadCache and C:\Users\%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Xamarin   See also [Cleaning Up Space on Your Xamarin Development Machine](https://montemagno.com/cleanup-up-space-xamarin-dev-machine/)  Please note that this also clears some Logs ...

Comment: @Benl Done that too doesn't do anything!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was caused not just by VS but also because of some incompatibility with my `Xamarin.Build.Download` package.

Updating it to 0.4.11 and updating my VS to latest solved it for me.